Landscape On Premises - Error when clicking on description from the main page
System error
An unexpected error has occurred. This event has been logged.
We apologize for the inconvenience.
Please use Community Support for assistance or purchase an Ubuntu Advantage support contract for expedited technical help.
OOPS ID: ['OOPS-74928af835980ae12318969b112c7321']
Landscape version 24.04  This is a new installation.
I rebooted the server, ran apt update and upgrade, and rebooted.
I'm not sure if it is related, but most of the clients don't report their packages.  However, they all respond to the ping from the landscape server.
Where can I find more details about this error?
